# is it possible to create a section in vf page and add lightning components to it

Tags: visualforce-component

is it possible to create a section in vf page and add lightning components to it. Split a screen into two and then add lightning components.

Comment: You should edit your original question rather than create a same question again.

Comment: no I want to add lightning components. on a single screen I want to show two different pages

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

Step 1: your aura application should be global and extend ltng:outApp:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
```

Step 2: add a dependency to your application:

```
<aura:dependency resource="c:MyAuraLgtComponent"/>
```

Step 3: In your visualforce page:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
```

Step 4: In your visualforce page:

```
<div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:MyApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("yourNamespace:MyAuraLgtComponent",
          { label : "" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Make sure that the component you are creating with `$Lightning.createComponent()` has the same name as the component you would like to display on the visual force page.

Comment: I am not creating an application I am looking for Community.....

Comment: Post more detail in your question!